# Finding Solution to Infinite Exponential Sum of Infinite Products

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

An example would be an infinite exponential series of products of geometric series.

$S = \sum_{i=0}^\infty S_n $

$S_n = \exp\{ a \sum_{i=0}^n \rho^i + nC \}=  \exp\{a (\frac{1-\rho^{n+1}}{1-\rho}) + nC\}$

Where $\rho\in(0,1)$ and $C<0$

Does a closed-form solution exist? Or is there a reliable approximation method outside of the standard numerical methods (which are impossible for my application)?

Comment: "Asymptote" applies to a graph of 4y$ as a function of $x$. Do you mean, "asymptotics"? If so, as a function of what variable?

Comment: I mean what it converges to. It is clearly a convergent series. Maybe I should change it to "solution".

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Is it possible to find a closed form solution? Is there an accurate approximation method? For example, the above is a special case of $\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \exp \{ -bt\} = \frac{1}{\exp\{b\}-1}$

Comment: No, hip, *equations* have solutions, *problems* have solutions, convergent series have *values*. Also, don't you mean for $S$ to be a sum on $n$, not a sum on $i$?

Comment: In any event, the sticky part of the sum is of the form $\sum_n\exp(r^n)$, and there's no closed form for that.

Comment: What are "standard numerical methods", and why are they not applicable, here? Unless $C$ is negative, but close to $0$, $\rho$ smaller, but close to $1$ and $a$ rather large, I can't imagine any bigger numerical problems with that.